# Jmeter - How to perform data compare on two JDBC requests for the entire DB

Tags: jmeter

I want to compare data between two databases, where there are 700K records to be compared, and that number is increasing all the time. 
My architecture is:

[image]
[image]

Where based on the MAIN query i run:

JDBC1 & JDBC2 and, then i compare the data between JDBC1 & JDBC2.

If i put static limit in the main query,

```
select * from transaction_info
order by id asc 
limit 1000
```

everything works fine, and i know how to compare the data.
But, how can i make all this dynamic, so i can break-down the main query like:

```
1. Query first 1000 rows, then compare/assert.
2. Query next 1000 rows then compare/assert.
```

And all this to continue till the 700K records?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of your main query SQL, you can include a combination of LIMIT and OFFSET to get incremental fetch of rows and variabilize the OFFSET part like below in order to bring in the dynamism

```
select * from my_table limit 1000 offset ${offset_value}
```

For the offset variable, define a Counter config element whose starting value is 1000, increments by 1000 until a max value of 700K. In case you want each user to do this process, then check on "Track counter independently for each user"

[image]

This way, everytime you will fetch 1000 rows then the subsequent 1000 in sequence

---

**My suggestion for Test Plan**

You can remove the loop controller and place the sub-queries along with assertion as siblings to the Main query and define the Thread Group's loop count to 700. This way the main query along with the sub-queries and assertion are triggered 700 times with each time fetching, processing and asserting 1000 rows at a time.

**Sample Test Plan**

[image]

**Thread Group Loop Count Configuration**

[image]

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you helped me a lot. But, how can i put all of above under loop, and make the script fully dynamic?

Comment: So, when you say you want to put all of above under loop, what are you actually implying? My understanding is that you want to fetch 700K rows in main query in an incremental manner of 1000 row per iteration and compare/assert the sub-queries for those 1000 rows fetched by main query. In this case, I am not sure what role your Loop Controller is playing (parent of sub-queries). Please help in clarifying this. To answer your query, configuring 700 as loop count in Thread Group should essentially help Main Query fetch 1000 rows until 700K rows are fetched and carry out other processes.

Comment: Well, maybe i asked incorrectly since the beginning . If i fetch all 700K rows in the main query, takes too long to complete. Thats why i want: main query to be splited into: more main queries each with ex: 1000rows; like main1: 1000 rows. main2: another 1000 rows. thanks

Comment: Ok.. cool.. have a better understanding now and accordingly I have updated the answer. Please let me know in case you are having some issues.

Comment: Thanks for the latest update, but this way seems not applicable to me, coz, the actual run is defined based on another query. So 700K is not static number. But, i will create another thread with all the latest requirements from my and, and close this as accepted. Thanks